# Call JSON in Website using jQuery POST Method

Tags: jquery, html, css, json, rest

I have created Java REST API, so I want call JSON in my website (created by using HTML & CSS) by using jQuery, This is POST method and my JSON is,

```
{
    "sessionID" : "25574",
    "interactiveChannel" : "CC_INTERACT_TEST",
    "audienceLevel" : "Customer",
    "relyOnExistingSession" : false,
    "debug" : false,
    "audienceID":[
     {
       "name":"CustomerID",
       "valueAsNumeric":"200",
       "valueDataType":"numeric"
     }
   ]  
}
```

So, how to POST this JSON using jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the $.post method. How it works:

```
 $.post(url, data, callbackFunction);
```

Ex:

```
var data = {
   myExampleProp: myExampleValue
};

$.post('www.mydomain.com/api/sessions', data, function() {
    // Successfully posted
});
```

You could also use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) which uses [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead of callbacks. This is to avoid the infamous callback hell. It's also easier to work with.

In my example I use a plain object but you can also send a string (JSON).

Comment: I did, but it show 415 error unsupported Media type

Comment: var data = {
   "sessionID" : "25574",
      "interactiveChannel" : "CC_INTERACT_TEST",
      "audienceLevel" : "Customer",
      "relyOnExistingSession" : false,
      "debug" : false,
      "audienceID":[
       {
         "name":"CustomerID",
         "valueAsNumeric":"200",
         "valueDataType":"numeric"
       }
     ]  
  }; 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.post("link",
        data,
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data.name + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});

Comment: above is my Post Request

Answer (score 0):

use ajax method it will work

```
var data = {"sessionID" : "25574","interactiveChannel":"CC_INTERACT_TEST","audienceLevel" : "Customer","relyOnExistingSession" : false,"debug" : false,"audienceID":[{"name":"CustomerID","valueAsNumeric":"200","valueDataType":"numeric"}]}

var saveData = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "http://127.0.0.1/abc/users",  //change the url to your url
      data: data,
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(resultData) { alert(resultData); },
      error:function(resultData){alert("Error Reading url or data");}
});
```

in your java add consumes(request mediatype) and produces(response mediatype)

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/users"}, method = RequestMethod.POST,
    consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
```

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/startSession", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 
 public Status sendStartSession(@RequestBody StartSession startSession) {
  System.out.println("Interactctive channel = " + startSession.getInteractiveChannel());
  return interactDemoService.sendStartSessionRequest(startSession);

 }

Comment: Above is my Java Code

Comment: @sunil updated my answer please check now and dont forget to change the ajax url to your post url

refernce : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-consumes

Comment: check my ajax code updated it might work now and please post your java method to receive this post request

Comment: try removing content-type line and 
please post your url so that i can test it and provide you a accurate result

Comment: public Status sendStartSessionRequest(StartSession startSession) {
  try {
   NameValuePairImpl audienceIdParameter[] = buildParameters(startSession.getAudienceID());
   NameValuePairImpl intilaParameters[] = buildParameters(startSession.getParameters());
   Response response = interactAPI.startSession(startSession.getSessionID(),
     startSession.isRelyOnExistingSession(), startSession.isDebug(),
     startSession.getInteractiveChannel(), audienceIdParameter, startSession.getAudienceLevel(),
     intilaParameters);

Comment: if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.STATUS_SUCCESS) {
    status.setStatusCode("0");
    status.setStatusMessage("success");
   } else if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.STATUS_WARNING) {
    for (AdvisoryMessage message : response.getAdvisoryMessages()) {
     status.setStatusCode("1");
     status.setStatusMessage(message.getMessage());
    }

Comment: } else if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.STATUS_ERROR) {
    for (AdvisoryMessage message : response.getAdvisoryMessages()) {
     status.setStatusCode("2");
     status.setStatusMessage(message.getMessage());
    }
   }

Comment: } catch (RemoteException re) {
   status.setStatusCode("2");
   status.setStatusMessage(re.getMessage());
  }
  return status;
 }

Comment: Sorry, but my services is on local server, is there any another way

Comment: first check your post url works with curl 

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d {\"username\":\"user\",\"password\":\"abc\"} http://localhost:8080/api/login/